# Dropping factors which levels have observations smaller than a specific value-R

Tags: r, filtering, r-factor

Let I have such data frame(df1) with factors:

```
factor1  factor2  factor3
-------  -------  -------
d        a         x
d        a         x
b        a         x
b        c         x
b        c         y
c        c         y
c        n         y
c        n         y
c        n         y
```

I want to drop factors from this data frame which one of elements have less than 3 observations.

In this data frame factor1 has 3 levels(d,b and c). However d level has frequency 2. So I want to drop factor1 from this data frame.

Resulted data frame should be as:

```
factor2  factor3
-------  -------
a         x
a         x
a         x
c         x
c         y
c         y
n         y
n         y
n         y
```

How can I do this using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `lapply` and `table`:

```
df1[, lapply(c(1,2,3), FUN = function(x) min(table(df1[,x]))) >= 3]
```

and, a little more generic:

```
df1[, lapply(1:ncol(df1), FUN = function(x) min(table(df1[,x]))) >= 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```
df <- data.frame(col1=rep(letters[1:4], each=3),
                 col2=rep(letters[1:2], each=6),
                 col3=rep(letters[1:3], each=4))

ddf[, sapply(df, function(x) min(nlevels(x)) > 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) min(nlevels(x))>2, df1)
```

(based on the results in one of the upvoted posts)

Or it could be also

```
Filter(function(x) min(tabulate(x))>2, df1)
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Fastest and most compact. You should note that `nlevels()` safely returns 0 on all non-factor variables. Also if we want to make this canonical, should parameterize: `Filter(function(x, max.nlevels=2) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a quick helper function that checks how many unique instances of each level exist with a quick call to `table()` -- look at `table(df$fac1)` to see how this works. Note this isn't very robust, but should get you started:

```
df <- data.frame(fac1 = factor(c("d", "d", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")),
                 fac2 = factor(c("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "n", "n", "n")),
                 fac3 = factor(c(rep("x", 4), rep("y", 5))),
                 other = 1:9)

at_least_three_instances <- function(column) {
  if (is.factor(column)) {
    if (min(table(column)) > 2) {
      return(TRUE)
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  } else {
    return(TRUE)
  }
}

df[unlist(lapply(df, at_least_three_instances))]
```